# C# double to int conversion issue

Tags: c#

I have a simple conversion in C#

```
double dindex,bindex;
int    index;

for(double pr=1100;pr<=1101;pr+=0.1)
{
    dindex = Math.Round(pr,1);
    bindex = dindex/0.1;
    index = (int)bindex;
}
```

I have printed value of dindex, bindex and index, the last line should convert to int but it is not always correct, the output looks as follows:  How can I make the converted int on column 3 (index)to be equivalent to double in column 2(bindex)?

```
1100   11000     11000
1100.1   11001     11000
1100.2   11002     11002
1100.3   11003     11002
1100.4   11004     11004
1100.5   11005     11005
1100.6   11006     11005
1100.7   11007     11007
1100.8   11008     11007
1100.9   11009     11009
1101   11010     11010
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The last column (not line) looks pretty integer to me. So does the second one. Keep in mind: *integer conversion cuts of the decimal places*, e.g, rounds down. Try printing the second column with full precision.

Comment: You're facing floating point numbers precision issue.

Comment: What is the solution?  I want column 3 to be equivalent to column 2?

Comment: Then why don't declare `index` as well double?

Comment: index is used to index an array

Comment: Use `decimal` instead of `double`. `decimal dindex,bindex;`,  `for(decimal pr=1100;pr<=1101;pr+=0.1m)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you'd expect rounding and truncation to produce the same result. But if you want to get the same result from truncation, you can add 0.5 before the truncation.

```
index = (int)(bindex + 0.5);
```

Answer (score 2):

int index = Convert.ToInt32(bindex);

Comment: `int index = 1001;
 float bindex = 1002;
  if (bindex > index) {
    index += 1;
  }`
So 
`if (bindex > index) {
    index += 1;
  }`
Should work.

Comment: great idea but when I try it, the condition is never true.  I also printed (bindex-index) the value is always 0!  I cannot detect the error programmatically ! I cast it to (double).

Comment: Odd, I ran this: `using System;

public class Test
{
 public static void Main()
 {
 double dindex,bindex;
 int    index;

 for(double pr=1100;pr<=1101;pr+=0.1)
 {
     dindex = Math.Round(pr,1);
     bindex = dindex/0.1;
     index = (int)bindex;
         if (bindex > index) {
       index += 1;
   }
     Console.WriteLine(" " + dindex + " " + bindex + " " + index);
  }
 }
}` and I got the correct result...

Comment: It may help if you added more detail to your answer to explain a little as well as adding such detail as you have in comments to your answer rather than posting as a comment

Comment: I must be doing something wrong.  This should work also.

Answer (score -1):

Double usually doesn't work with fixed decimals. In your example,

```
1100.1   11001     11000
```

actuall, the value stored for `bindex` is `11000.999...`, which gets the roundend down to `int` which is `11000`. If you would like precision and are certain your values are not ridiculous high (read : in `float` range), you can use `float` instead of double. Othwerwise, try using `decimal`.